# Consultation about error and eclipse stop working for me

Tags: android

i got error when i trying to open eclipse

Version 1.4.2_03 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.5 or greater is required.

what i need to download ?  (i work on Windows-7)

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need JDK 6.  You can get it from [the Oracle download site.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)